# Postgres copy many files with program argument

Tags: postgresql, macos

I want to import a few thousand files into my postgres database which runs on a macbook. I need an other way to import all these files in an efficient manner. It currently failes as the argument list is to long.

Command I've issued:

```
COPY pwned from PROGRAM 'cat /Volumes/Secret/Collection/1/*.txt' DELIMITER '|';
```

Error I get:

```
ERROR:  program "cat /Volumes/Secret/Collection/1/*.txt" failed
DETAIL:  command not executable
```

The reason is as I can't cat the files:

```
cat /Volumes/Secret/Collection/1/*.txt
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

How can I import all my files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pipe to xargs your problem should be solved:

```
COPY pwned from PROGRAM 'cat /Volumes/Secret/Collection/1/*.txt | xargs -n1' DELIMITER '|';
```

The reason to use `-n1` is because you'll need to restrict it to 1 argument per command line, otherwise you'll get an error on import as it will try to insert more than one line of the copy for a row in your table, which would fail in most instances.